# BufferedReader reading each newline a comma

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

My code is suppose to read a file with integers separated by newlines and prints them out in reverse. My code would work only if the integers are on in the first line, but if the integers are separated by a new line it gives this

Opening file...

File opened
Before Reverse Order [5 12 3 5 4 , 0] 
After Reverse Order [ 4 5 3 21 5, 0]

With the file containing this

5 12 3 5 4
0

How can make my code instead display: 0 4 5 3 21 5

Below is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String line =null;
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> arrayList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    System.out.println("Opening file... \n");
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
        System.out.println("File opened");

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()!= 0)  {
            //String[] input = line.split(" ");
            arrayList.add(new StringBuilder(line));
        }
        in.close();


        System.out.println("Before Reverse Order " + arrayList);

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
              arrayList.get(i).reverse();
    }

        System.out.println("After Reverse Order " + arrayList);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to reverse the arrayList itself. You only reverse each StringBuilder.

```
Collections.reverse(arrayList);
```

Anyways, there seems to be no use for a list at all. Just append directly to the StringBuilder. Something like this should do the trick:

```
// ...
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()!= 0)  {
    sb.append(line);
}
in.close();

System.out.println(sb.reverse().toString());

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you, I guess I didnt need the ArrayList at all.

Comment: If you don't append a space, two consecutive lines won't have any separator

Answer (score 1):

Use only a single `StringBuilder`, append a space between each line :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String line =null;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    System.out.println("Opening file... \n");
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
        System.out.println("File opened");

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()!= 0)  {
           s.append(line);
           s.append(" ");
        }
        in.close();


        System.out.println("Before Reverse Order " + s);

        s.reverse();

        System.out.println("After Reverse Order " + s);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives :

`Opening file... 
File opened
Before Reverse Order 5 12 3 5 4 0 
After Reverse Order  0 4 5 3 21 5`

Comment: The `try/catch`-block is important. `in.close()` should be done in `finally`-block.

Comment: I agree, I used the OP code, I did not modify this part

Answer (score 0):

dont use readLine. you can use read() function. it gives chars. and you can check "\n" or " " char manually. line this:

```
 int c = r.read();
    while (c != -1){
        char ch = (char)c;
        if (ch == '\n' || c == ' '){
            String num = buf.toString().trim();
            if (num.length() > 0){
                arrayList.add(new StringBuilder(num));
            }
            buf.delete(0, buf.length());
        } else {
            buf.append(ch);
        }
        c = r.read();
    }
    String num = buf.toString().trim();
    if (num.length() > 0){
        arrayList.add(new StringBuilder(num));
    }
```

and, also you should call `Collections.reverse(arrayList);`

Answer (score 0):

lupz' answer is correct. Either before or after your `arrayList.get(i).reverse();` you add `Collections.reverse(arrayList);`

The complete file is here:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String line =null;
    ArrayList<StringBuilder> arrayList = new ArrayList<StringBuilder>();
    System.out.println("Opening file... \n");
    try 
    {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
        System.out.println("File opened");

        while((line = in.readLine()) != null && line.length()!= 0)  {
            //String[] input = line.split(" ");
            arrayList.add(new StringBuilder(line));
        }
        in.close();


        System.out.println("Before Reverse Order " + arrayList);

        for(int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
              arrayList.get(i).reverse();
    }
    Collections.reverse(arrayList);

        System.out.println("After Reverse Order " + arrayList);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a file with many lines where each line can contain integers separated by a space.  In that case I would  use the split function to get the integers on each line. I am also assuming that you dont need to check that the values in the file are actually integers.  Otherwise you would have to use Integer.parseInt(String p).  You  can use ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList to keep track of all the Integers.  Then for each line use arrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")).  The assumption is that each integer is separated by one space only.  Then at the end you can just reverse arraylist.